# Returning a list from function

Tags: python, list, function, return, google-calendar-api

I know, the question is dumb and easly googleable on internet.
I did it, and that did not help me.
I'm working with the Google Calendar API for Python (3.7.1)

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dtparse
from datetime import datetime as dt
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'

start = '2018-12-26T10:00:00+01:00'   # Let's say your start value returns this as 'str'
tmfmt = '%d %B, %H:%M %p'


class Calendar():

    def getEvents(self):
        """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
        Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
        """
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        store = file.Storage('token.json')
        creds = store.get()
        if not creds or creds.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

        # Call the Calendar API
        now = dt.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                              maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])
        if not events:
            print('No upcoming events found.')
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            stime = dt.strftime(dtparse(start), format=tmfmt)
            items = str(stime + event['summary'])
            print(items)
            return items

"""
 Tried aswell   str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in items)
                return str1
"""


    def Events(self):
        print(self.getEvents())


x = Calendar()
x.Events()
```

I modified it in order to return the events with a human readable date format. 
Anyway, when i `print(stime + event['summary'])` in `getEvents()`, I get a normal output..
When i try to print it in another function (at last it shall be displayed in a tkinter label), It either doesn't work, or it prints the first item, or the last one...

How is this achieved?

Comment: You should show the actual and expected output to make things more clear for readers. Anyway, I can see that your code contains a `return` inside a loop. That means that the function will return at the end of the first iteration. Is it really what you want?

Comment: Well I need it to return the items, if there are.. I could move it out but I can't see the diffrence it would make regarding my problem

Comment: I don't understand why you can't see the difference it would make. Try it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a list is achieved by literally returning a list object, not calling return multiple times.

Indeed, your function will exit the first time it encounters a return statement. For example:

```
>>> def func():
...     return 1
...     return 2
...     return 3
... 
>>> func()
1
```

We don't get a list of `[1, 2, 3]` - we exit with the value returned by the first return we encounter.

Specifically, you have a return inside a loop. This will cause the function to exit on the first iteration through this loop.

Your loop over events probably wants to look like this instead:

```
ret = []
for event in events:
    # ... snip...
    ret.append(items)
return ret
```

You probably want to consider renaming some variables too - `items`, for example, only refers to a single item.